# Boot error for custom compiled kernel - gave up waiting for root device

Tags: 10.04, boot, kernel, grub2

I have installed lucid on my Lenevo Laptop (Y 410 series , x86 platform) and it is working fine. Now I have compiled kernel 2.6.37 downloaded from the kernel tree. I followed usual procedure of compiling kernel (`make menuconfig`, `make`, `make modules` etc). Then I created the initrd image using `mkinitramfs` and updated my grub using `update-grub` command.

`update-grub` detects the initrd image of the compiled kernel. However when I boot from this kernel it gives me following error:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! root=UUID=/... does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.19.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.10.3-7ubuntu1.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a lost of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

and then it falls onto initramfs prompt.

I have tried following solutions discussed in different Ubuntu forums:

1. disable uuid and point root=/dev/sda8 (sda8 is where my kernel image resides (both default kernel and compiled one) from /etc/default/grub
2. compile kernel using CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y [suggested here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1435968)
   Still I am unable to boot from the compile kernel.

Could someone please suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [KernelCheck](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/how-to-compile-kernel-in-ubuntu-easy.html) for this, it makes it very easy to compile the kernel with just a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

`root=` should be root disk partition (where `/` filesystem is), not a boot partition.

Are you sure you compiled in the drivers for your disk controller and root filesystem?

Comment: I am talking about root parameter in grub config file.When I write GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true in /etc/default/grub , it passes root=/dev/sda8 as parametr to grub. I verfied this by pressing 'e' in grub2 on both the kernels. Now problem is default kernel boots and  compiled does not.

Comment: About compilation of drivers , I am using make menuconfig and not disableing any driver. Doesnt it mean it shoul compile all the required drivers ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - To fix it, you must run:

```
make modules_install
```

and then run this again:

```
sudo make install
```